# Reading storage on any USB device

Tags: windows, usb

Is it possible to read storage on any USB device?

For example: I have Bluetooth headphones which, when switched on, play audio fragments like "Noise cancellation on." and "Connecting to `<device name>`.", etc. When I connect my headphones to my PC via USB (for charging purposes), the device obviously doesn't show up in the Windows explorer, since (I assume) the device is not marked as a mass storage device. However, is there a way to access the (limited) storage this device has anyway, to, for example access the aforementioned audio fragments?

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not possible. It is up to the manufacturer to make it possible but in general they don't. If your device has an upgradeable firmware and you want to change these files you need to reverse the factory firmware and change them before uploading it to the device. It's extremely unlikely the firmware for a headphone to deploy heavy anti-reverse engineering / anti tamper measures, it's not like it's a router or similarly sensitive device so this should be an easy task. Relatively speaking, of course.